# Entity Framework Include and Navigation Property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entitydatasource

I use Asp.net and EF 4.

In my model I have two Entities: `CmsGroupsTypes` wich has a navigational property called `CmsContents` to Entity `CmsContents`.

I'm using an `EntityDataSource` control together with a GridView.

I need return `CmsGroupsTypes` but filtering theme using the Navigational Property and `QueryStringParameter`.

With the following code I receive an error:

```
'ContentId' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[CmsModel.CmsContent(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection
```

---

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" DefaultContainerName="CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CmsGroupsTypes" Include="it.CmsContents.ContentId"
    Where="it.CmsContents.ContentId == ContentId">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ContentId" QueryStringField="ContentId" DbType="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I have an equivalent version in LINQ and it is working but I have to implementing directily on the EntityDataSource Control.

```
      // Get ContentId from Query String.
        int myContentId = Convert.ToInt32(ContentIdFromUrl);
        // Find all GroupsType for a specific Content.
        var myGroupsTypesList = from g in context.CmsGroupsTypes
                                where g.CmsContents.Any(x => x.ContentId == myContentId)
                                select g;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick guess: `Include` takes the name of a navigation property, so instead of:

```
Include="it.CmsContents.ContentId"
```

shouldn't it be

```
Include="it.CmsContents"
```

?